# What solutions exist when apps don't download or update on iOS 6?

Tags: ios-appstore, software-update, ios

I've been having a problem with installing and updating apps after upgrading to iOS 6 on my iPad (3rd gen). When I click the `Install` or `Update` button the button, it turns inactive with "Installing" word on it, while the app's icon on the SpringBoard says "Waiting".

I tried even buying a new app, but it is exactly the same. Deleting the app and trying again doesn't help. What's interesting the problem doesn't seem to affect my iPhone 4S.

I noticed several people at Apple Support Communities are affected by this, too.

Comment: I declined the flag to make this CW. the downside of denying rep seems to outweigh any benefit CW would offer here. Feel free to ask again on [meta] and we can review if this is the best choice for CW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been fighting with this for several days now, and I think I finally cracked it.  Check your iTunes Downloads (iTunes->More->Downloads) in iOS for stuck downloads.  I had a music video that appears to have been gumming up the works.

Here's the official Apple KB article covering this:

- [TS1583 - iTunes Store: "Error (-50)" when downloading purchased content](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1583)

Prior to pausing that download I had tried rebooting, logging out of iTunes and all the other suggestions on lots of other blogs/sites/forums.

Comment: Jeremy you legend! All it was was a huge iTunes d/l... The free Sherlock episode from 12 days of xmas. Caused me a lot of heartache for the last day!

Comment: SO Glad I could help.  It was driving me crazy before I found the solution.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and after none of the other suggestions worked (changing date/time, shutting down and restarting), I went to Settings > iTunes & App Stores, then clicked on Apple ID > Sign Out.  After signing back in, I was able to start downloading apps again.

Comment: This worked for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that you can try to resolve this issue:

- delete the stuck apps, sign out of the App Store, sign in back again and try installing again
- delete the stuck apps, turn on Airplane Mode for about 30 secs, turn it off and try installing the apps again
- stop or delete any remaining iTunes downloads. *This worked for me*. I've been downloading quite a few songs from my iTunes in the Cloud and some of them got stuck. It was not until I deleted the stuck and remaining iTunes download that app downloads would resume.

Answer (score 1):

Before you deleting apps just try powering off the phone and then on again - worked for me - so glad I didn't delete the 17 apps that were stuck and then have to go and find them all again!

Comment: This is a very good minimal solution, I've also had luck placing the device into AirPlane mode and then going through the normal shutdown / restart process. By getting to a good network (WiFi with good bandwidth) helps let this process complete by itself. iOS 5 had single threaded downloads / installations of apps, and iOS 6 enables many at one time and may expose some networks that are simply not capable of handling that many simultaneous downloads in a reasonable amount of time. Too many active tasks would ensure none complete.